# Use FacialFeatures in Python Web API?

Tags: machine-learning, python, computer-vision, mxnet-format

Under the hood, `FacialFeatures` uses the net-model *ResNet-101 Trained on Augmented Casia WebFace Data*. I would like to see a tutorial-style answer on how one would implement the downvalues of `FacialFeatures[]` in python by exporting the network?

Alternatively, using Mathematica behind a flask app to serve http requests with images would be another answer.

Comment: Have you tried simply finding the network implemented in Pytorch or any other python-compatible Neural Networks library? Exporting the network out of Mathematica has a host of gotchas and difficulties that may not be worth it since the network was almost certainly implemented in Python in the first place - eg here: https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet

Comment: But that one's a year old. I haven't found one that does all the things FacialFeatures[] does...

Comment: If external function could be used in a webserver behind some queue then that would work too, instead of exporting stuff and code to python...

Comment: The `NetModel` you're talking about is also a year old: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/ResNet-101-Trained-on-Augmented-CASIA-WebFace-Data (at the bottom). The source website is also valuable.

Comment: You could try something like `CloudDeploy[FormPage[{"i" -> "Image"}, FacialFeatures[#i, "Age"] &]]` (or `APIFunction` or similar. I don't know that you will get great results this way though - `FacialFeatures` is an expensive function.)

Comment: What about deploying this locally behind a python web server using zeromq or externalevaluate